# net::err_cert_weak_signature_algorithm visting website on MacBook

Tags: macos, google-chrome, ssl, hsts

A visitor browsing our website:
https://www.construct.net

Is reporting they can't visit the website and are seeing this error:

[image]

I can't reproduce this error - does anyone have suggestions on what might be causing this?

Comment: Google has started to warn users when SSL/TLS configurations are weak on servers. Use the latest version of Chrome or Chrome Beta and you should be able to reproduce the error.  Go here : https://observatory.mozilla.org/ : and enter `www.construct.net` and scan your site. I did already so it may be cached and you'll get immediate feedback. It's pretty bad. Go to the bottom of each "tab" and follow links to get better server-side configurations.

Comment: @hrbrmstr cannot reproduce this in Chrome Canary.

Comment: Neither can I (I didn't visit the site before since I don't tend to visit random internet sites or follow random links — I just pasted the host into the observatory). It's likely that you at one time had an HSTS configuration and it got cached. The SSL/TLS config is horribad, regardless, and needs fixing. Point your user(s) here: https://www.thesslstore.com/blog/clear-hsts-settings-chrome-firefox/ to have them clear the HSTS cache.